# Html Table right border not showing on print

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, printing, html-table

I'm trying to print a HTML page which have a table but it is not printing the right border of the table

[image: Print preview image]

My CSS code is as below

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
  @page { size: landscape; }
  .header, .header-space,
.footer, .footer-space {
  height: 100%;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
 table {
        border: solid #000 !important;
        border-width: 1px 0 0 1px !important;
        border-collapse: collapse;
         width: 100%;
    }
    th, td {
        border: solid #000 !important;
        border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px !important;
    }
</style>
<style>
th, td { border: 1px solid; padding: .2em .7em; }
</style>
```

I tried my best but failed again and again. Currently working with google chrome

Comment: Try using `box-sizing: border-box` so the border is part of the 100% width. You can also try an absolute width like `29cm` (this is how I print A4 invoices).